# How to write "progressive" unit tests? C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dry

I have code as below:

```
public async Task<ValidationResult> ValidateAsync(Request request, Client client, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    if (request is null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(request));
    if (client is null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(client));

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.Parameter1) && request.Action != "merge")
        return MissingParameter(nameof(request.Parameter1));

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.Parameter2))
        return MissingParameter(nameof(request.Parameter2));

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.Parameter3))
        return MissingParameter(nameof(request.Parameter3));

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.Parameter4))
        return MissingParameter(nameof(request.Parameter4));

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.Parameter5))
        return MissingParameter(nameof(request.Parameter5));

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.Parameter6))
        return MissingParameter(nameof(request.Parameter6));

    // Validate length of some parameters
    // Later validate for different combinations (some parameters aren't allowed when specific parameters are present)
    // And other validation (e.g. whether client is allowed to requested parameter's values)

    return new() { IsValid = true };
}
```

And I want to write test to it.

Firstly, I check if method throws if request or client is null. It's simple.

But later, I have to test if appropriate error is returned (caused by missing parameter). To do this, I have to firstly write tests for `parameter1`, later test for `parameter2`, later for `parameter3` and so on. Before validating each parameter, I have to set parameters that are earlier than currently tested to be valid.

So in each method I repeat the same code many times.

Later I validate e.g. length of some parameters. For every parameter I want to check I have to earlier set up earlier parameter to avoid `return MissingParamater()`

Later I want to validate for different combinations, so I have to set up properly all parameters to avoid `MissingParameter` and `return` caused by invalid length.

I hope you understand my problem now. Every test repeats the same code, the same mocks and often only one thing changes.

So my question it how would you write tests for code like provided by me, and whether is there a possibility of create "progressive" unit tests (by this I mean that one test says "I end here", and the next test will start testing from the point where the earlier test ended work.

Comment: Personally I’d have no problem with one test that covered all the cases you show. Others will disagree.

Comment: Is it worth writing tests for code like this, especially tests involving mocks?  The tests will require more code than the actual code under test.  Ordinarily I would use a validation framework for this sort of thing; then you don't write tests, you just visually verify that your data elements are decorated with the proper attributes.

Comment: Indeed, I simplified this code too much. That's because the whole validation is about 160 lines long. It even contacts the database and uses other validators via DI. But it all happens in one context (validating one request) and the problem is still the same. Shall I add whole code?

Comment: Sounds to be a job for a `[Theory]` with `InlineData` and your test method gets parameters for each request parameter and an additional parameter `expectedErrorMessage`. So you write one test and call it with different combinations to test each scenario.